# 2 years old code do not work now(WindowController alloc)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Below code worked 2 years before

today I try to rebuild

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

@class EnterWindowController;


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;

    EnterWindowController *vEnterWindowController;

}

@property (retain,nonatomic) EnterWindowController *vEnterWindowController;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#import "EnterWindowController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate;
@synthesize vEnterWindowController;

 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    if(!vEnterWindowController)
    {


        vEnterWindowController=[[EnterWindowController alloc] init];

    }


    [vEnterWindowController showWindow:self];//point A
 }
```

the enterwidow related to EnterWindowController does not display,
I set the break point at A, and found that vEnterWindowController is nil,
it looks like

```
 vEnterWindowController=[[EnterWindowController alloc] init];
```

does not work and always returns nil.

Your comment welcome

Comment: If you assign the created object to a local variable does that work? Like EnterWindowController *a = [[EnterWindowController alloc] init];

Comment: have you ARC enabled now but not two years ago?

Comment: Not surprising.  That's like *ancient* in dog years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax works for me using Xcode 6.1:

```
if (!vEnterWindowController)
{
    vEnterWindowController = [[EnterWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"yourWindowNibName"];
}

[vEnterWindowController showWindow:self];
```

BTW you could also, in your .h file use

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, , NSWindowDelegate> {

    @public

    EnterWindowController *vEnterWindowController;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

and you won't need to synthesize `vEnterWindowController`. You also don't need to synthesize window in your `.m` file.

Adding the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol to `AppDelegate` can also make it handy to receive notofications about the main window.